# How do I get all refs that point to a commit in git?

Tags: git, branch, commit, git-remote, git-tag

Is there any way to get a list of refs (including tags, branches, and remotes) that point to a particular commit in git?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`git show-ref | grep $(git rev-parse HEAD)` shows all refs that point to `HEAD`, the currently checked out commit.

`git show-ref` shows all refs in your git repo.

`git show-ref | grep "SHA goes here"` shows all refs that point to the SHA of a commit.

Comment: Output looks like: `fd881751702cf279442abeae382c54c11725beeb refs/heads/master`
`fd881751702cf279442abeae382c54c11725beeb refs/remotes/origin/master`

Answer (score 5):

**Human-readable format**

For the last commit (ie, HEAD):

```
git log -n1 --oneline --decorate
```

Or to specify a particular commit:

```
git log -n1 --oneline --decorate fd88
```

gives:

> `fd88175 (HEAD -> master, tag: head, origin/master) Add diff-highlight and icdiff`

To only get the tags/refs/remotes, pass this through `sed`:

`$ git log -n1 --oneline --decorate | sed 's/.*(\(.*\)).*/\1/'`

> `HEAD -> master, tag: head, origin/master`

For bonus points, add an alias for this:

```
decorations = "!git log -n1 --oneline --decorate $1 | sed 's/.*(\\(.*\\)).*/\\1/' #"
```

Comment: `git log -1 --pretty="%D"` will be easier ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using only pipes. Outputs the identical SHA of the two branches if they are the same, fails with no output and exit code 1 otherwise.

```sh
git rev-parse A B |\
 uniq |\
 sed -n -e '${1p}' -e '2q 1'
```

- `rev-parse` the 2+ branches
- `uniq` only unique lines
- `${1p}` if last line and first line, print
- `2q 1` else quit with exit code 1
  may be GNU specific. Try `q` if it doesn't work.